# Differentiating between the characteristics of a positive and a negative charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, field-theory

I am keen in knowing the *physical* difference between the fields produced by positive and negative charges. Thus far, I can only give myself an unsatisfactory answer: that in a field produced by a positive charge, a + test charge is repelled, and that in a field produced by a negative one, such a charge is attracted. I find this bothersome, for it relies on *knowing* a field (the test charge, here) is positive beforehand.

And so: Is there some greater fundamental difference, from which we are able to distinguish the two forms of charge?

Answer (score 2):

Positive and negative are just names. Nothing happenst if  all the charges in the universe change + by -.

If you have two + particles change both to -, they feel the same force.

You are right on

> in a field produced by a positive charge, a + test charge is repelled, and that in a field produced by a negative one, such a charge is attracted.

but the test charge is only a convention and if we change all charges and the convention of the test charg, then nothing new wiil happen.